# Ajax Toolkit AsyncFileUpload not working inside a normal Panel

Tags: asp.net, asyncfileupload

Referring to the following:
[Ajax Asyncfileupload doesn't work as soon as I put it in a  control](http://forums.asp.net/t/1566071.aspx)

I am having the same issue. I am not using a Master page though. I have an AsyncFileUpload control in a Panel, within an update panel.

Any ideas as to what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `AsyncFileUpload` you must set the right params in the `form` tag, that is placed in your Page or MasterPage:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

If you don't set the right enctype and method **UploadedComplete will never fire**, and you won't be able to get **FileUpload.FileBytes** since **FileUpload.HasFile** returns true only during UploadedComplete execution.

I suppose that in your page you haven't set the right enctype.

Besides, prevoius versions of AsyncFileUpload didn't work on Chrome. 2011 July version (4.1.50731.0) solved the problem.