# How to insert image by creating folder in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, file-io, insert

I need to create a folder within another folder(total 2 folders), in that I need to insert the image.

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{



    AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload async = (AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload)sender;

    if (async.HasFile)
    {


        if (image1 != null)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(MapPath("~/images/" + SelectHotels.SelectedItem) + image1);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        image1 = e.FileName;
        if (File.Exists(MapPath("~/images/" + SelectHotels.SelectedItem + "/") + image1))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Change Image", "alert('Image with same name already exit please change name and upload');", true);
            image1 = null;

        }
        else
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + SelectHotels.SelectedItem)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + SelectHotels.SelectedItem)+image1);

                str = "~/images/" + SelectHotels.SelectedItem;

                str1 = "~/images/" + SelectHotels.SelectedItem + "/" + image1;

            }
```

Comment: [Follow this post, Hope it will help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561106/ajax-toolkit-asyncfileupload-not-working-inside-a-normal-panel

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
    public void EnsureDirectoriesExist()
    {

            // if the \pix directory doesn't exist - create it. 
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"~/Folder_Name/")))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~/Folder_Name/"));
            }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (FileUpload1.HasFile && Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".jpg")
            {
                // create posted file
                // make sure we have a place for the file in the directory structure
                EnsureDirectoriesExist();
                String filePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Folder_Name/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);


            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Not a jpg file";
            }


    }
```